# Thread Code...anything wrong with this, must use java 1.4

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a servlet automatically firing up when the app server starts, and in its init(), I'm making another thread:

```
init(){ new FooThread().start() }
```

in FooThread(), i want to periodically check the status of a DB value, then depending on the value, make a web service call. When these two tasks complete, I want the thread to sleep to wait a certain period then repeat.
This cycle would just continue forever.

FooThread:

```
public class FooThread implements Runnable{
  Thread t;

  FooThread(){
    t = new Thread(this, "FooThread");
  }

 public void start(){
   t.start();
 }

  public void run() {
    try{
      while(true){
        //do the db check, then conditionally do the web services call
        logger.info("*** calling sleep() ***");
        Thread.sleep(50000);
        logger.info("*** now awake ***");
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("*** FooThread interrupted");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what is your question?

Comment: Voted to close as there is no question here.  "Review my code" isn't generally well-received on SO at least without specific criteria you're looking for.

Comment: @Petro Semeniuk : The question is in the title. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don’t start threads in your constructors because it could lead to race conditions and indeterminate behavior. Instead, call the `start()` method after constructing the object.

EDIT:

The reason it's bad is because you *may* publish the `this` pointer before the 
constructor has finished.

Comment: can you explain more please, what kinds of indeterminate behaviors could happen ?

Comment: if I do not want to extend Thread, but I want to implement Runnable, I have no choice but to do what I did?

Comment: Not true.  You can move the code that starts the thread to the top of the run method.

Comment: sorry, not getting it...start() calls run(), you said to put start() in run()?

Comment: @John - yes that can cause a problem - and thats why you favor composition over inheritance.  Mark the class final - I mean, you can always write bad code.

Comment: Amir I deleted the comment - I looked to quickly and thought you were arguing against this answer then realized you posted it :)

Comment: other reference on the publishing of 'this': http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618.html

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is considered unsafe publication.  When -this- reference escapes the constructor you have the possibility of sending a partially constructed object to thread class.

In your example what if your class and the run method looked like this:

```
public class FooThread implements Runnable{
  Thread t;

  private int someInt;
  private Object someObject;

  FooThread(){
    t = new Thread(this, "BBSThread");
    t.start();
    someInt = 10;
    someObject = new Object();
  }

  public void run() {
     System.out.println(this.someInt);
     System.out.println(this.someObject);     
  }
}
```

It is possible there that someInt prints 0 and someObject prints null.  Your object is technically constructed but not completed.

Comment: would this concern go away if someInt and someObject initialization were the first lines in the constructor?

Comment: Yes they would.  All writes to fields that happen before the start of a thread are then visible to that thread.  However, imagine if a class extended FooThread and overwrote the run method.  That subclass has other fields that are created in its constructor.  The child class is now partially constructed because the thread started before the subclass assigned the fields in its constructor

Comment: i think i see, thx for the explanation. since i'm not doing any of that in this specific case, i do not have that concern, right?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new variable `t` inside `FooThread` if you subclass from `Thread`. An instance of `FooThread` then already is the thread. And you don't need to call `start()` on it in the constructor.

A proper use of `FooThread` inside `init()` would be:

```
FooThread ft = new FooThread();
ft.start();                           // calls run() inside FooThread
```

In the code you lined out above the constructor of `FooThread` doesn't need any logic, `run()` looks fine.

Comment: `FooThread`, despite its name, is an implementation of `Runnable`, not a subclass of `Thread`.

Comment: @Mark Peters: oh, I overlooked that part. Thanks :). I added the _if you subclass from Thread_ -part

Comment: Extending `Thread` is typically bad form anyway.  It unnecessarily couples the work to the execution environment of that work.  IMO it's better to do `Thread ft = new Thread(new FooThread()); ft.start()`

Comment: @Mark Peters: I don't understand that. I thought the only difference is that using `Runnable` would allow to subclass from another class and, therefore, inherit some base logic, while subclassing from `Thread` obviously only provides logics from the `Thread`-class.

Comment: yes, should not have Thread in the class name, otherwise, any performance or bad form issues in run() with what I want to achieve?

Comment: @Mark Peters: how many new threads is your idea making, it seems 2?

Comment: @bmw0128: No, just one.  `FooThread` is not actually a thread since it implements `Runnable`, but doesn't subclass `Thread`.

Comment: @sjngm:  No, implementing Runnable alone basically says "here's a batch of work".  Passing it to a thread and starting the thread says "I want to execute that batch of work in this thread".  But you could just as easily pass the Runnable to an ExecutorService for example.  Or you could pass the same batch of work to two different threads and have them BOTH do it.  Extending thread introduces coupling to the execution environment that doesn't need to be there.

Comment: @Mark Peters: following up with your idea of using Thread ft= new Thread(new FooThread()); ft.start()...FooThread class would only have run() method, no need for the constructor, right? Alo, how did u format to highlight part of your comment?

Comment: @bmw0128:  The `new FooThread()` is needed because `run()` is an instance method.  You need an instance of the `Runnable` to be able to invoke its `run` method.  But the default constructor is fine, so yes you do not have to explicit define a constructor.  You can highlight inline code by surrounding it with backticks: `\`someCode()\``.  http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help